# Key press only fire with MDI form,not with MS form

Tags: c#, mdi

I have an MDI form with many mdi child forms. To catch key press event on those form, I used ProcessCMD key. But there is a problem. If I create a new form that doesn't belong to the parent form(parent form is MDI form and new child form is a normal form). I couldn't catch key press event on new child form. I don't know why this happened.

My app has many forms so that I can't create a class and then fix each form by inherriting a class to store which form is open.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this `doesn't belong to the parent form`? it does not have `MdiParent` set or `Parent` set? or both?

Comment: yup..my new child form doesn't have MdiParent set. I just have my form showed diaglog..

Comment: who can help me pls?..I need to solve this problem soon..